# Symfony access decision manager strategy is always affirmative

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I try to change the access control decision strategy in a Symfony project but it doesn't seem to work.

I have the following in my `security.yaml`:

```yaml
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
        allow_if_all_abstain: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/dev/test, roles: [COMPLEX_TEST, ROLE_OTHER] }
```

I need both `COMPLEX_TEST` and `ROLE_OTHER` to be granted for the route to be accessible (`COMPLEX_TEST` is tested by a custom role voter).

But when I try to access the route, only the `COMPLEXT_TEST` voter is called, and that's because it allows the access and the strategy is still `affirmative`.

I can say this because when debugging the code, I can see that the value in  `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager` is **always** `affirmative`, no matter what I set in the `security.yaml`.

For now I've created a compiler pass that forces the strategy to `unanimous`, but it's kind of a hack:

```php
class FixAccessDecisionManagerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if ($container->hasDefinition('security.access.decision_manager')) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition('security.access.decision_manager');
            $definition->setArgument('$strategy', AccessDecisionManager::STRATEGY_UNANIMOUS);
        }
    }
}
```

With the compiler pass I can see that the value in `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager` is correcly set to `unanimous` and the access control works as expected.

Do you see what I am missing? Or is it a bug in Symfony? My Symfony version is `4.4.7`.

Thank you for your time.